# Hadoop MapReduce - How to improve parallelism

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have been given a problem. I have a dataset (CSV files) which contains airport and flights information, like the airport code, flight code, date and time the flight arrived, date and time the flight was supposed to arrive, etc. For now, I have the datasets for only two years - 2006 and 2007. I am using java mapreduce API for the solution.

I have to find out the average flightDelays in each airport for the two years and store the output in two separate files - one for 2006 and another for 2007. The output should also be sorted by the airportCode.

My approach goes like this:

```
Full Dataset ->
map(<lineNumber , lineText>) ->
<(year,airportCode) , flightDelay> ->
custom Partitioner to partition only by year ->
reduce((year,airportCode) , flightDelaysList) ->
output (year, airportname, averagedelay)
```

This works, since all intermediate output with same year will be sent to the same Reduce task and the ones with same (year,airportCode) combination will goto the same reduce() method.

However, in my case since only two years - 2006, 2007 exist, there will be only two reducer tasks spawned. This seems like a bad practice, since if I have 10 task trackers to do my work, I am utilizing only two for my reduce phase.

Can somebody suggest a solution where multiple reducers are spawned to do the work and later, some sort of  merge could combine files for a single year and we still have two output files - one for 2006 and another for 2007? Hope I could explain the problem well. Please feel free to comment for any clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enhance the performance and paralellism of your job, I would suggest the following enhancements:

- add a combiner for accumulating all delays and entries per mapper
- use a compound key of year and airport to increase the number of reducers and save the time of writing a custom partitioner
- now two options: 1)either use tez for a map -> reduce -> reduce or 2) write a file per airport and year and merge them afterwards with HDFS utils

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is good and it will achieve good parallelism as more data comes in to the picture (more number of years).

Still if you want your approach to utilize maximum number of reduce slots for parallelism, you can make sure you create that many necessary number of partitions by doing necessary change in your partitioner. 
And you need to handle overhead of merging the files with same year in single sorted file.

Comment: I need to work on the data for these two years as of now, and its pretty huge (in GBs). If I create more than two partitions, it would create multiple files. I want to keep data specific to each year in its own file. Is there a way to identify which output files belong to each year, and then merge the files in a way that their contents are again sorted by airportCodes? Even if its possible, wouldn't it take up more time than what was saved by achieving parallelism? Is there a better way to solve problems where keys are limited and the number of values corresponding to each key is large?